# UITextVew tap in the middle of a word and place the cursor there

Tags: ios, uitextview

In the common behavior of UITextVew if the user taps in the middle of a word the cursor gets placed at the beginning of that word, or in other cases it selects the whole word.

I would like to entirely disable this and just let the user tap anywhere in the UITextVew and place the cursor just there.

Also I would appreciate to know if this is possible too for a UIWebView with contentEditable enabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get this behavior you have to build the text view yourself using core text. Or your only support iOS7. There you will have TextKit.

Comment: If you can put it as an answer @dasdom I think I'll accept it

Comment: This was driving me nuts until I came across your post - I thought it was something I had done! Quite a bizarre 'feature' really. I think I'm going to need to write my own subclassed textview!

Comment: I need the same thing in my application. Does anyone got some solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this behavior you have to build the text view yourself using core text. Or your only support iOS7. There you will have TextKit.